# Why C drive in my windows 10 get filled very often though i don't have much in it

Tags: windows, caching, memory-management, system, drive

I have 183GB of total space in C drive in my windows 10 but it gets filled easily . The software's i installed mainly was visual studio and sql server . I can have only 3 database maximum in my sql server.My C drive gets filled very quickly and i get out of memory problem very frequently . When i searched for solution in google there were many answers saying to clear my temp,%temp%,recent and prefetch. I have tried all  of that but still the issue persist. Is there any other solution for this?

Thank you!!